# Golang with GORM. How to correctly pass model type into method?

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-interface

I have next GORM model

```golang
package entity

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

type InterfaceEntity interface {
}

type User struct {
    InterfaceEntity
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
```

I try to pass GORM entity type into base crud repository. My base crud repository:

```
package repository

import (
    "billingo/model/entity"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "reflect"
)

type CrudRepository struct {
    *BaseRepository
}

func NewCrudRepository(db *gorm.DB) CrudRepositoryInterface {
    repo := NewBaseRepository(db).(*BaseRepository)
    return &CrudRepository{repo}
}

func (c CrudRepository) Find(id uint, item entity.InterfaceEntity) entity.InterfaceEntity {
    fmt.Println("--- Initial")
    var local entity.User
    fmt.Println("--- local: ", reflect.TypeOf(local), local)
    fmt.Println("--- Item:  ", reflect.TypeOf(item), item)


    fmt.Println("--- Values")
    c.db.First(&local, id)
    fmt.Println("--- local: ", reflect.TypeOf(local), local)
    c.db.First(&item, id)
    fmt.Println("--- Item: ", reflect.TypeOf(item), item)
    return item
}
```

As you can see here are `item` and `local` variables in `Find()` method.

I pass `item` using next way from service:

```
func (c CrudService) GetItem(id uint) entity.InterfaceEntity {
    var item entity.User
    return c.repository.Find(id, item)
}
```

It seems what `local` and `item` must be equals and behavior must be equivalent.

But output is

```
--- Initial
--- local:  entity.User {<nil> {0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} }
--- Item:   entity.User {<nil> {0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} }
--- Values
--- local:  entity.User {<nil> {1 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} test 1}
--- Item:  entity.User {<nil> {0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} }
INFO[0000] User info                                     user="{<nil> {0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} }" user-id=1

(/home/mnv/go/src/billingo/model/repository/CrudRepository.go:29) 
[2019-05-17 17:07:37]  unsupported destination, should be slice or struct
```

`item` passed from service leads to message

> unsupported destination, should be slice or struct

How to pass `item` correctly, I need behavior like with `local`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I has fixed it.

Now repository method `Find` called from service with `&item`:

```golang
func (c CrudService) GetItem(id uint) entity.InterfaceEntity {
    var item entity.User
    return c.repository.Find(id, &item)
}
```

And repository method pass `item` without `&`:

```golang
func (c CrudRepository) Find(id uint, item entity.InterfaceEntity) entity.InterfaceEntity {
    c.db.First(item, id)
    return item
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Gorm doesn't want to unmarshal the data into your empty interface type.

Even though you are passing in a struct that implements that particular interface, it still remains typed as the interface after passed. You need to cast that `item` interface back to your `User` struct.

Like `item.(entity.User)`

Comment: Thanks for response. `item.(entity.User)` works well. But I need to create more abstract method what don't knows about type of model. I'm novice in Golang. May I use something like `item(reflect.TypeOf(item))`?